# How to show donate with paypal button in android?

Tags: android, paypal

I am developing a application for non-profit organisation. I want to donate using paypal. I integrated the paypal using their SDK. The problem is when I open the paypal it displaying a button Pay with paypal but I need donate with paypal . Please any one help me how to do this

Answer (score 0):

paypal itself has an button create tool where u can choose if it shall contain donate or pay with.

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donate-intro-outside

Comment: Thanks for the answer I am using paypal API for android this one for web application